# How do I call the ListView using CustomScrollView and display all the elements?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I have a ListView that is seperated by a divider and is called as shown below.
I have called all the elements however the last tile gets cut on my screen. I've tried adding the SliverPadding around the List but it doesn't help and crops the list even more.
This is the code for my ListView:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
            child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                      left: 18.0),
                  child: Text("Puppies",
                      style: khomeStyle.copyWith(color: kOrange, fontSize: 27)),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: ListView.separated(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    //shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    //padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Divider();
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          isThreeLine: false,
                          leading: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Image.network(
                                  'https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/LhWrTxh5MaOb_6IY-fgLxH75SI8=/2121x1193/smart/filters:no_upscale()/golden-retriever-puppy-in-grass-923135452-5c19243546e0fb000190737c.jpg'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Helllo",
                                style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    color: kOrange,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            'This is a message',
                            style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ));
                    }),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is what the ListView looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyL2x.png

Comment: Why `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` ?

Comment: because i want the entire page to scroll and not only the list inside the page @dev-aentgs

Comment: Ok. According to your code everything is inside the `CustomScrollView` so entire page will scroll. By adding `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` we are effectively stopping the `ListView` from displaying its elements which are outside of the visible region of the screen. It will also result in clipping if device orientation changes. Remove `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` and try again.

Comment: so i tried removing it however now the list scrolls but the page doesn't. So the title I have on the top of the page stays fixed

Comment: Can you please get a reproducible example up on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev)?

Comment: have you tried using `SingleChildScrollView()` and use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` , this will make complete page scrollable

Comment: @SimranAswani Are you aiming for something like [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) ?

Comment: Yes but i cant set the constraints of my list when i use that and there is a lot of empty space below the list. Can you site an example? @chetansuri

Comment: Nope im not trying to achieve something similar to sticky headers. Actually im trying to do the opposite. I want the header to scroll with the list and the page.@dev-aentgs

Comment: Yes ive made the necessary changes. @Christian

Comment: @SimranAswani - Is there any use of Stack(). If you want you can achieve UI in Image using Rows and Columns.

Comment: In `Slivers` there is `SliverPersistentHeader` for achieving that, for reference [old example](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) @SimranAswani .

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for Slivers, try below code. this will scroll till last item and nothing will be cropped.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: 10,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                  isThreeLine: false,
                  leading: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/LhWrTxh5MaOb_6IY-fgLxH75SI8=/2121x1193/smart/filters:no_upscale()/golden-retriever-puppy-in-grass-923135452-5c19243546e0fb000190737c.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Helllo",
                        style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: kOrange,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    'This is a message',
                    style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                  ));
            }),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```